# What does it mean to "Provide a table dump" in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dump

How can I perform a table dump to give to the client?

To try and provide as much info:

- I am using both SQL 2005 and 2008
- Existing databases are simple, like POS, Inventory, Tracking types
- I was asked to provide a table dump (of a certain table in a certain database in a certain server)
- No more info provided by client--just that they would like a table dump
- What is a "table dump", what formats are available, how do I create one to send to client?

If I missed more info, please let me know -- I'm really after the generic kind of table dump generation (if possible through T-SQL, better :) )

Comment: You can use "Generate Scripts" with "Script" set to "Schema and Data" to do this. Although it gets less practical the more rows you have.

Comment: Generating Scripts might solve the problem for current table but I think we need to handle references too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your client wants the file in a format that they can work with. In my experience this is something that can be opened in Excel either natively or as a CSV. My first suggestion would be to clarify the requirements with the client.

For now, let's assume they want a CSV file. Assuming you have Sql Server Management Studio, you could use the Import/Export wizard to export the contents of a database (selecting a specific table) to a variety of formats including Flat File and Excel. Right click on the database, choose tasks, export data and follow the steps.

This link shows how to use Import/Export wizard and the BCP command line tool. The BCP command line tool would be a more repeatable and scriptable option. http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2011/01/sql-server-export-table-to-csv.html

If you have SSIS running on the server or available, you could use that to create a package which would be another reusable solution.

Answer (score 2):

It means to provide a copy of the table's data.

Typically, it means provide a export of the table, including its definition and insert statements, as a script that can be executed to recreate the table from scratch.

However, It could mean a binary and/or proprietary format too, that is written/read by a database utility.

The common concept is that the table's contents may be restored from the dump.

Comment: +1 for the really quick response (being the first!) -- This time I'll go with ASalvo's answer (for selecting an answer) since he mentioned a way to export it -- but really, thank you!